# Finding a telescoping difference for sum involving a factorial denominator

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am attempting to find whether the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{(n+1)!}$ converges or not through finding a telescoping difference, however I am stuck on trying to find a partial fraction as the ones I have come up with do not have one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may observe that, for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$,
$$
\dfrac{n}{(n+1)!}=\dfrac{(n+1)-1}{(n+1)!}=\dfrac{(n+1)}{(n+1)!}-\dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}=\dfrac{1}{n!}-\dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}.
$$

Comment: *"Le bon vieux truc !"*. Cheers, Olivier !